# Puppet: hanging at Schedule[weekly]

Tags: puppet

Why would puppet hang at Schedule[weekly]?

I'm running puppet in a masterless setup, so to apply by manifest I'm just running `puppet apply /etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp`

In debug mode, these are the last things it says before it just hangs

```
debug: /Schedule[never]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[daily]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[monthly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[puppet]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[hourly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
debug: /Schedule[weekly]: Skipping device resources because running on a host
```

If I send a SIGINT, it says

```
Exiting
debug: Storing state
debug: Stored state in 0.03 seconds
debug: Finishing transaction 69992657242500
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is identical to a question I almost posted two days ago.  In my case, the problem turned out to be that I was recursively applying permissions to a directory that went from being mostly empty to having many files in a deep hierarchy, and it was just taking a really long time for Puppet to finish processing things.

I used `strace` to figure out what was going on, like this:

```
strace -f -s80 -e 'trace=!rt_sigprocmask' puppet apply ...
```

This shows a system call trace of the puppet process (and any child processes), which can help you figure out if Puppet is stuck or if it's simply really busy.

One thing you can do is start paring down your Puppet manifests to see if removing a particular module removes the problem.  Without seeing your configuration it's hard to offer a definitive answer, but hopefully this offers some starting points.  Please feel free to ask questions and I'll help out as I can.

We also run a masterless Puppet configuration at my office.  We use `yum` for distributing our Puppet configuration to clients hosts.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out it was a file resource that was ensuring directory and had recurse true. Removing recurse solved it.